# Topology of shapes

Tags: general-topology

I am beginner in this subject. I understand at least definition of topology. However, I don't get how Topology: a Set with topology on that Set accounts for shapes. How would you describe the topologically a torus? or Sphere? Is it possible to represent it in the form $(X,S)$, what will $X$ and $S$ be for a torus?

If this question is Not a Real Question, instead of answering, just add a comment, I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topology is something quite abstract. For many geometric shapes, you can start with something more intuitive: **Distance**

Whenever you have a notion of measuring distance on a shape, you can turn this into a topology. Let's first look at what to call a distance: Denote the distance between two points as $d(x,y)$, then we require some intuitive constraints

- Distance is never negative and $d(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$.
- Distance is symmetric, i.e. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$.
- There are no "shortcuts", i.e. $d(x,y) + d(y,z) \geq d(x,z)$.

A set with such distance function $d$ is called a **metric space**. So by just considering shortest pathes on a torus, a sphere ..., you have made them into metric spaces.

Now what's our topology? Having distance defined, we can look at the set of points closer than some radius $\epsilon$ and we call $B_\epsilon(x) = \{y : d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$ a ball around $x$ with radius $\epsilon$. By definition, we now call a subset $A$ of our metric space *open* iff we can find a tiny $\epsilon$-ball around every point in it, so our topology is
$$ \tau = \{ A \subset X | \forall x \in A \exists \epsilon > 0: B_\epsilon(x) \subset A \} $$
You can check that this defines a topology on your metric space.

Comment: Ok, if I got it correct, it's the metric that defines the shape of torus or sphere, right? I do have some knowledge of metric spaces but cannot connect them with topology. And can't upvote! already used all i had for today. sorry!

Comment: Yes, the metric (or topology) defined what we refer to as shape. The bare definition of a torus would just be a set of points in $\mathbb R^3$, but we had no idea of how to relate this points without interpreting this in some kind of topology (of course $\mathbb R^3$ already comes with its own metric which we can re-use on subspaces)

Comment: For example, you can equip every space with the discrete metric, which is $d(x,y) = 1$ for distinct $x,y$ and $d(x,x)=0$. With every point being equally far from every other point, we cannot distinguish any geometries any more.

Answer (score 0):

One standard approach to the torus is as follows.

First, define a *surface* to be a compact topological space where every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open disc.

Then, prove that every surface is homeomorphic to a polygon with edges identified in pairs.

Then define a torus to be a surface homeomorphic to a square with opposite pairs of edges identified. Well, you have to be a little careful about the orientation of the edges, or else you're liable to get a Klein bottle; the orientations have to be "opposite", in the sense that if you travel one edge of a pair in the chosen orientation, and continue past the edge, around the square, when you reach the other edge in the pair you are going *against* the orientation.

For a sphere, you can take a "polygon" with two edges (this is topology, not geometry, so such a thing makes sense), and identify the two edges, oppositely oriented.